# mongodb Replica Set and change default port

Tags: linux, mongodb, server, centos

I am trying to set up a mongodb Replica Set, but it give me an error

" **Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded.........."**

if I try to add other member into the replica set by using the command

rs.add('hostname:27017'). Anyone know what the problem is? Do I need to change the

default port of other mongodb?

Comment: of course different nodes of a replica set must run on different ports

Comment: I change the default port of second member to 19999 but it still give me this error "replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: 10.10.10.119:19999 failed with No route to host" "